# DatePicker doesn't work in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, datepicker, yii2

I'm trying to add the datepicker in my GridView, but somehow it isn't working. Could someone help me to solve that?

Here is my GridView:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        [
            'atrribute' => 'employment_date',
            'value' => 'employment_date',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
                 'model' => $searchModel,
                 'attribute' => 'employment_date',
                 'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-m-d'
                 ]
            ])
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I also used a widget in my `_form.php` file:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'employment_date')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false,
            'clientOptions' => [
                'autoClose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-m-d'
            ]
         ])?>
```

It simply says `DatePicker not found`. I thought that is not in the `use section`. But when I'm trying to add it by `CTRL+SHIFT+I` it says `cannot be resolved`. Then I've tried to paste it by simply writing it, but it's saying `Class 'dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker' not found`. What I'm doing wrong? I've installed the composer and I have added `"2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget" : "~1.0"` line in my `composer.json` file

Comment: Did you run `composer update`?

Comment: I have type that command in my `cmd`?

Comment: Yes. After adding something to `composer.json'  you have to run that command to download the files

Comment: I just typed it in my cmd and it says `Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Windows\System32`...

Comment: you have to be in the folder where the `composer.json` file is

Comment: @gmc If there are a lot of `composer.json` files in `xampp directory`, in which place should I look for the correct one?

Comment: In the root folder of your current yii2 project

Comment: @gmc Well, thanks, I found it and in cmd type `composer update`, update worked correctly, but it didn't solved the problem

Comment: @gmc Do you have the idea what else I can be doing wrong?

Comment: Go to the vendor folder and see if the files of the plugin are there. If not, you have not installed the plugin. Maybe you are working with the wrong `composer.json` file

Comment: How to know if the correct files are in the `vendor` directory? Coz now I have a lot of folders and I don't know where to check

Comment: `vendor\dosamigos\datepicker`

Comment: There are no `dosamigos` folder in my `vendor`, so I guess I'm trying to update the wrong `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this line to `require` section in `project-directory/composer.json` file

> "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget" : "~1.0"

2. Then run in project directory command:

> composer update

3. After that, use again `Ctrl + Shift + I` to autoimport class.

---

Other way to install this extension is to use this command:

```
composer require 2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget:~1.0
```

in `project-directory/composer.json`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is in the shell or cmd go to the directory of your project, then run

```
composer update
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I start used the datepicker from kartik-v. It's more advanced.

use in composer
`php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker`

and this link for more help :
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker